# Merge classes based on a property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of `Person` class objects.

```
List Persons = new List();

class Person
{
    public int CatId{ get; set; }
    public int SubcatId{ get; set; }
}
```

Now the instances of `Person` class may have same **CatId** or **SubcatId**. But they are not the same   for two classes at the same time making each instance uniqe. For example:

```
Person1: {CatId = 1, SubcatId = 1}
Person2: {CatId = 1, SubcatId = 2}
Person3: {CatId = 2, SubcatId = 1}
Person4: {CatId = 2, SubcatId = 2}
```

Now I have another class `MergedPerson` that merges `Person` classes that have the same **CatId**

```
class MergedPerson
{
    public int CatId{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a list of `MergedPerson` objects: List `MergedPersons` using `Linq` ?

```
MergedPerson1: {CatId = 1}
MergedPerson2: {CatId = 2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`:

```
var MergedPersons = Persons
                   .GroupBy(x => x.CatId)
                   .Select(x => new MergedPerson { CatId = x.Key })
                   .ToList();
```

If you want to group persons based on more than one property, you can use a [Composite Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

```
var MergedPersons = Persons
                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.CatId, x.SubcatId })
                   .Select(x => new MergedPerson { CatId = x.Key.CatId })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Selman22, If I wanted to go one level higher what should I do then? I mean if I had a third property and I wanted to group based on two first properties?

Comment: @Vahid then use `.GroupBy(x => new { x.CatId, x.SubcatId }).Select(x => new MergedPerson { CatId = x.Key.CatId, SubCatId = x.Key.SubCatId });`

Comment: The answer you gave above is completely correct for what I wanted. It seems that I had not been able to ask the question in a good way. So I I'm still having problems. I posted a new question that defines my problem better. I'd appreciate it if you help me with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315624/merge-the-items-of-a-list-based-on-properties-using-linq