# Group items in a list based on two properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Column` class as below:

```
public class Column
{
    public int LocId { get; set; }
    public int SecId { get; set; }
    public double StartElevation { get; set; }
    public double EndElevation { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of `Column` objects:

```
List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();
```

For example:

```
Columns:
{
    Column1: { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 }
    Column2: { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 }
    Column3: { LocId = 1 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 320, EndElevation = 640 }
    Column4: { LocId = 2 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 }
    Column5: { LocId = 2 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 }
}
```

I want to apply the below algorithm to the above list using **Linq**.

Go through the `Columns` list and:

- *(A) Choose a list of items that have the the same `LocId`.*
- *(B) Then from that list choose another list of items that have the same `SecId`.*

This will give me a list hopefully which I will perform other things on it.

So applying the above algorithm on the data above will be like this.

```
                                       Columns List
                ---------------------------------------------------------
               | Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5 |
                ---------------------------------------------------------
                                            |
                                            |
                                           (A)
                                            |
                                            |
                        --------------------------------------------
                        |                                          |
                GroupBasedOnLocId                         GroupBasedOnLocId
                        |                                          |
                  -----------                                 -----------
                  | Column1 |                                 | Column4 |
                  | Column2 |                                 | Column5 |
                  | Column3 |                                 -----------
                  -----------                                      |
                       |                                           |
                      (B)                                         (B)
                       |                                           |
          -------------------------                   -------------------------
          |                       |                   |                       |
          |                       |                   |                       |
 GroupBasedOnSecId        GroupBasedOnSecId  GroupBasedOnSecId        GroupBasedOnSecId
          |                       |                   |                       |
          |                       |                   |                       |
       Column1                 Column3             Column4                 Column5
       Column2
```

How can I accomplish this using LINQ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.GroupBy` with composite key.

Sample code:

```
List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>
{
   new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 },
   new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 },
   new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 320, EndElevation = 640 },
   new Column { LocId = 2 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 },
   new Column { LocId = 2 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 }
};

foreach (var group in Columns.GroupBy(c => new { c.LocId, c.SecId }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("group: LocId = {0}, SecId = {1}", group.Key.LocId, group.Key.SecId);
    foreach(Column column in group)
        Console.WriteLine("  item: StartElevation = {0}, EndElevation = {1}", column.StartElevation, column.EndElevation);
}
```

You can transform the group any way you want:

```
foreach (var res in Columns.GroupBy(c => new { c.LocId, c.SecId })
                           .Select(g => new
                           {
                               g.Key.LocId,
                               g.Key.SecId,
                               MinStartElevation = g.Min(c => c.StartElevation),
                               MaxEndElevation = g.Max(c => c.EndElevation)
                           }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("LocId = {0}, SecId = {1}, MinStartElevation = {2}, MaxEndElevation = {3}",
        res.LocId, res.SecId, res.MinStartElevation, res.MinStartElevation);
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP requested; they wanted two-level grouping, not grouping by a composite key.

Comment: @Avish OP stated `This will give me a list hopefully which I will perform other things on it.`, so let's wait for his response.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks this is what I wanted. I'd like a full-linq answer but apparently only this answer worked.

Comment: @Vahid What do you mean by **full-linq**? I added the sample of group processing, is it what you want?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov OP drew a nice diagram clearly showing a two-level grouping, if they wanted something else they'd have drawn that. I'm surprised they chose this answer after going through so much trouble clarifying they want something else entirely.

Comment: @Avish OP didn't say anything about processing of results between **A** and **B** steps. So I supposed that all he needs is the result after **B** step, which is effectively grouping by two keys. PS. Just to let you know I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: I guess only @Vahid knows. :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Your update to the answer is simply brilliant. How did you know that I wanted to put `StartElevation` and `EndElevation` properties into that use. You read my mind? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a two-level grouping as your diagram indicates, you need to use `GroupBy` twice:

```
var grouping = columns
  .GroupBy(col => new { col.LocId, col.SecId }) // create groups by LocId+SecId
  .GroupBy(group => group.Key.LocId); // re-group by LocId only
```

Then you'll have a sequence of groups, each group having a having an `int` key (that's the `LocId`) and consisting of a sequence of other groups, each one having a composite key of both `LocId` and `SecId`, and consisting of a sequence of columns (matching those `LocId` and `SecId`).

You can then access the two-level grouping by `foreach`-ing over each level. For example:

```
foreach (var locGroup in grouping) {
  Console.WriteLine("LocId: " + locGroup.Key)

  foreach (var secGroup in locGroup) {
    Console.WriteLine("  SecId:" + secGroup.Key.SecId)
      Console.WriteLine("  Min StartElevation: {0}", 
        secGroup.Min(col => col.StartElevation);
      Console.WriteLine("  Max EndElevation: {0}", 
        secGroup.Max(col => col.EndElevation);

      foreach (var column in secGroup) {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0} -> {1}", column.StartElevation, column.EndElevation);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to be able to find a specific node in the tree, you can use `ToDictionary` and `ToLookup`:

```
var lookup = columns
  // group columns by LocId
  .GroupBy(col => col.LocId) 
  // create a dictionary from the groups to find them by LocId,
  // where the value of each entry is a lookup of its own columns by SecId
  .ToDictionary(             
     locGroup => locGroup.Key, 
     locGroup => locGroup.ToLookup(col => col.SecId));
```

Then you could do things like:

```
var locId = "123";
var locGroup = lookup[locId];
Console.WriteLine("LocId {0} has {1} sub-groups", locId, locGroup.Count);
Console.WriteLine("LocId {0} has {1} total columns", locId, 
  locGroup.Sum(secGroup => secGroup.Count()));

var secId = "456";
var secGroup = locGroup[secId];
Console.WriteLine("LocId {0}, SecId {1} has {2} columns", 
  locId, secId, secGroup.Count());
```

Comment: @Thanks Avish, can you please tell me how to access the items of this your `Linq` produces?

Comment: I edited my answer to include example of how to iterate the resulting two-level grouping tree, as well as an option for creating a lookup where you can find nodes in the tree by their key. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: My problem is that I can't access other properties of the Column class later. For example if Column1 and Column2 also have a `Section` property which I need to include in the final merged group how should I transfer that?

Comment: You can access the properties on individual columns only when you're down to the column level. At any of the other levels (Loc-group or Sec-group) you'll need to aggregate these values (e.g. by using `Min` and `Max` shown above, or by introducing another level of grouping). This is very similar to the SQL `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51524/discussion-between-vahid-and-avish)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses **LINQ Query Syntax**. (Query syntax and **Method Syntax** are semantically identical, [but many people find query syntax simpler and easier to read.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx))

```cs
// Declare and then populate the LINQ source.
List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();

var query =
    from column in columns
    group column by new {column.LocId, column.SecId} into g
    orderby g.Key.LocId, g.Key.SecId
    select new
    {
        LocId = g.Key.LocId,
        SecId = g.Key.SecId,
        Columns = g
    };
```

Below you'll find a complete demonstration program for this LINQ query using the data you provided. I've preceded the demo program with its expected output. Also see the [live demo](http://ideone.com/qJT522).

**Expected Output**

```
LocId:1, SecId:1
  StartElevation:0, EndElevation:160
  StartElevation:160, EndElevation:320
LocId:1, SecId:2
  StartElevation:320, EndElevation:640
LocId:2, SecId:1
  StartElevation:0, EndElevation:160
LocId:2, SecId:2
  StartElevation:160, EndElevation:320
```

**Program**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class LinqGroupDemo
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var query =
            from column in GetSource()
            group column by new {column.LocId, column.SecId} into g
            orderby g.Key.LocId, g.Key.SecId
            select new
            {
                LocId = g.Key.LocId,
                SecId = g.Key.SecId,
                Columns = g
            };

        foreach (var key in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LocId:{0}, SecId:{1}",
                              key.LocId,
                              key.SecId);

            foreach (var column in key.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  StartElevation:{0}, EndElevation:{1}",
                                  column.StartElevation,
                                  column.EndElevation);
            }
        }
    }

    static private List<Column> GetSource()
    {
        return new List<Column>
        {
            new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 },
            new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 },
            new Column { LocId = 1 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 320, EndElevation = 640 },
            new Column { LocId = 2 , SecId = 1, StartElevation = 0, EndElevation = 160 },
            new Column { LocId = 2 , SecId = 2, StartElevation = 160, EndElevation = 320 }
        };
    }
}

public class Column
{
    public int LocId { get; set; }
    public int SecId { get; set; }
    public double StartElevation { get; set; }
    public double EndElevation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var results = columns
    .GroupBy(column => column.LocId)
    .Select(group => group.GroupBy(c => c.Sec.Id));
```

Comment: +1 from me for answering a split second earlier and including a link to GroupBy, and to offset the uncalled-for downvote.